# Mac bash doesn't remember alias

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a simpler alias to launch MIT-scheme from the Terminal so I did:

```
alias mit-scheme="/Applications/MIT-Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme"
```

Then I can launch MIT-scheme by simply typing `mit-scheme`.

However if I close this Terminal window and open a new one, when I type `mit-scheme` I get `-bash: mit-scheme: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the command will define it for the current shell, but that's it. There's nothing specific about macOS here — this is a bash thing. You have to run the command on every shell. To do this automatically, add the line to a sourced file such as `~/.bash_profile`.